# Button Object Changing to Even Object

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I am creating buttons, then putting them through as arguments to a function I created called (placement), but when I run them in as arguments and I try to print the type of this input, they become Event Objects, I don't understand why this occurs, I need them to remain as Button objects, because i want to change the text of a button after i click it

```
for column in range(self.column + 1):
    new_button = Button(new_frame, text = ' ', height = 10, width = 20)
    new_button.grid(row = r, column = c)
    new_button.bind('<Button-1>', func = lambda x=new_button: self.placement(x))

def placement(self, button):
    print(type(button))
    if self.current == 1:
        button.config(text = 1)
        self.current = 2
    else:
        button.config(text = 2)
        self.current = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A `bind` function requires a `event` argument, so you have to change your code to:

```
new_button.bind('<Button-1>', func = lambda event, x=new_button: self.placement(x))
```